# hashing ISBN of a book

Tags: c, hash

what would be a good way to hash the ISBN of a book? 
sorry for the confusion let me clarify, I want to hash the ISBN of books of size 1000. but the array might grow. its a hash table not encryption. the programming language is c but this is a general question. I want to know the standard hashing method for ISBN used in the industry or your suggestions.

Comment: What kind of hashing, cryptographic (e.g. SHA1) or for hash tables (Object.hashCode)?

Comment: This is way too open ended to even try to answer. What is your expected data sample set? Size? Purpose of hashing?

Comment: good way to hash is to use a good hash algorithm..

Comment: Also what platform? Java, C#, C++, etc?

Comment: An ISBN already includes a checksum. See section 4.4 of: http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/html/usm4.htm. Given the size of an ISBN, trying to hash it rarely makes much sense; leaving off the checksum, it's 9 decimal digits, which works out to ~32 bits to start with.

Comment: Can you post your code that is storing the numbers now? A hashing algorithm is not specific to one problem, say, hashing ISBN numbers. What remains is its time complexity and and collision rate. You (ideally) want one that doesn't require you to confirm a match by comparing four unsigned integers after comparing the hash, even if the hash itself is proven polynomial.

Comment: Why all the downvotes for this question? Since an ISBN is formed by specific rules, a "good hash algorithm" that works for random strings might not be optimal for an ISBN. For instance, the last digit of an ISBN is a check digit, so it should not be used as part of the hash. Language and platform are not so important when designing an algorithm. Important questions are : set size (how many books do you need to keep track of); are these ISBN-10 or ISBN-13; and are you planning on tracking other printed material (ISSN) also?

Comment: ok let me clarify again. what I want to do is when I type the ISBN I want to get to the data immediately, and I only want to use a size of 1000 arrays but I also want to accommodate future additions to the array.

Comment: I am using ISBN 13, and I am not going to track anything.

Comment: just use python, homework buddy

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there's an industry standard *hash function* for ISBNs.  The industry standards have to do with the 978 prefix and other prefixes, and with how ISBNs get allocated to different publishers.  In my own ISBN-based application, I use a bog-standard hash function intended for use with strings.  I take no advantage of the fact that the ISBN is limited to decimal digits (or in the case of the check digit, decimal or X), and I go ahead and hash the check digit even though it's redundant.  It's so fast to hash a 10- or 13-digit string that doing special-case stuff might actually slow things down.

Popular hash functions for C programmers include the Jenkins hash functions; also Hsieh, Torek, SuperFastHash, and murmurhash.  I'm sure there are others; you can search for them.  Also you'll find a collection at http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that on such trivial data sizes the specific algorithm rarely matters.